# How to export JSON from powershell into node.js

Tags: json, node.js, powershell, socket.io

I am using the `Azure Node SDK` to try this.

I am exporting the following JSON from powershell

```
get-process | Select Name,ID,VM,WS | Select -First 10 | ConvertTo-Json
```

That gives me something like this.

```
{
    "Name":  "AcroRd32",
    "Id":  6776,
    "VM":  185810944,
    "WS":  63762432
}
{
    "Name":  "BCMWLTRY",
    "Id":  1128,
    "VM":  580022272,
    "WS":  38010880
}
{
    "Name":  "conhost",
    "Id":  332,
    "VM":  52039680,
    "WS":  3592192
}
```

Is there a way, I can grab this data from a node app.js file?
I am trying to work this into `node.js / express` and `socket.io` code.

I have called some web-based API's from powershell and successfully passed the variables to the REST API.
http://poshcode.org/3369

However, I am having a hard-time passing the powershell `JSON` data to a local `node.js`  instance.

Any help / pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't let your node app drive this? I.e., use [`child_process.exec`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to call your powershell command and capture the output.

Comment: I havent tried that. Let me try that out and I will post back.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Shouldn't there be some commas and square brackets in there somewhere?